# CABasicAnimation connection with Timer / Swift

Tags: swift, cashapelayer, cabasicanimation

I want to present my ShapeLayer Circle as reverse Progress-bar connected with my Timer, so if the timer is set to 1 minute, the CABasicAnimation should run off the shapeLayer constantly 1 Minute long.

This is the code I already have but I don't know how to achieve my destination. Can someone help me?

```
let shapeLayer = CAShapeLayer()
    let trackCircle = CAShapeLayer()
```

...

```
 let circularPath = UIBezierPath(arcCenter: center, radius: 140, startAngle: -CGFloat.pi / 2, endAngle: 2*CGFloat.pi, clockwise: true)
        trackCircle.path = circularPath.cgPath
        
        trackCircle.strokeColor = UIColor.lightGray.cgColor
        
        trackCircle.lineWidth = 20
        
        
        trackCircle.lineCap = .round
        
        trackCircle.fillColor = UIColor.clear.cgColor
        
        view.layer.addSublayer(trackCircle)
        
        //SetUp Circle
//        
        shapeLayer.path = circularPath.cgPath
        
        shapeLayer.strokeColor = UIColor.systemBlue.cgColor
        
        shapeLayer.lineWidth = 20
        
        shapeLayer.strokeEnd = 0
        
        shapeLayer.lineCap = .round
        
        shapeLayer.fillColor = UIColor.clear.cgColor
        
        view.layer.addSublayer(shapeLayer)
        
        
    }
    
    @objc private func handleTap() {
        print("Attemping to animate stroke")
       
        
        let basicAnimation = CABasicAnimation(keyPath: "strokeEnd")
       
        //0.8 = full circle
        value = 0.8 / goalCount

            
         //normal Value Step
         basicAnimation.fromValue = 0
         basicAnimation.toValue = value
    
        
        
        basicAnimation.fillMode = .backwards
        basicAnimation.isRemovedOnCompletion = false
        
            shapeLayer.add(basicAnimation, forKey: "urSoBasic")
        
        
        
        
    }
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Please attach an example gif file.

Comment: `CABasicAnimation` and `Timer` are both system classes that run for a specified amount of time. There is no method to make an animation automatically run for as long as a timer. Perhaps you could create a custom function that takes a `CABasicAnimation`, a targer layer, a duration, and a timer completion handler, and sets the duration of the animation while also starting a timer?

Comment: @RajaKishan Exactly like at the iPhone Timer, you set a time and then there is this circle animation which decreases constantly